# Retrieve bytea type as blob or file

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, prisma, bytea

I have a db model in postgres (using prisma) as follows:

```
model files {
  id    Int     @id
  title String?
  file  Bytes?
}
```

file is a `bytea` type and I'm using it to store files. When I retrieve the file, I get the results like this:

```
{"type":"Buffer","data":[104,101,108,108,111]}
```

How can I either retrieve it as a blob so I can send it to the front end to read as a file, or read that buffer data in javascript?

Comment: Usually you don't store files in your db, you store the metadata including where to get the actual file itself (i.e. an S3 location that the client can just load without needing your own server for that task, saving you bandwidth and money). However, that notwithstanding, assuming this is on the Node side (neither your post nor tags make that clear, so please still do that) it's a Buffer: [turn it into whatever you need](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html).

Comment: @Mike "*saving you bandwidth and money*" - well now you're paying S3 for their bandwidth… Storing files in the database [can have advantages](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BinaryFilesInDB), but as always [it's a trade-off](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/2445/188406).

Comment: "*When I retrieve the file*" - please post the code you are using for that

Comment: Of course, the whole point of S3 and other related services is that it's cheaper than handling the data yourself. If it's not, then store the files on your own server in an asset location and then still put only the metadata in your db. (with the asset URL, rather than the filesystem path)